# I can't fetch any rows from a Polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, polymorphic-associations, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I've set up 2 polymorphic associations on a table, I have no problem adding to the table but I can't seem to retrieve the added information.

Here's what I'm doing:

Post

```
belongs_to :posted, polymorphic: true
belongs_to :received, polymorphic: true
```

User

```
has_many :posted_posts, class_name: 'Post', as: :posted
has_many :received_posts, class_name: 'Post', as: :received
```

Group

```
has_many :posted_posts, class_name: 'Post', as: :posted
has_many :received_posts, class_name: 'Post', as: :received
```

users_controller.rb

```
def post
    authorize @user
    @post = Post.new(post_params)

    @post.received = @user
    @post.posted = @current_user

    if @post.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html {redirect_to root_url}
        format.js
      end
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html {redirect_to root_url}
        format.js
      end
    end
end
```

Post seems to be fine, but I should be able to retrieve the information by using

```
           <% @user.received_posts do |post| %>
                <%= post.content %>
            <% end %>


           <% @user.posted_posts do |post| %>
                <%= post.content %>
            <% end %>
```

But neither of these work. What am I missing? It's not bringing up an error. In fact, the logs aren't showing anything.. it's like it's being ignored. Do I need a method somewhere that does some lifting? I though the rest is handled by rails..

Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE - Logs

```
    Started GET "/!/David" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-18 12:02:32 +0100
Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
Parameters: {"username"=>"David"}
User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 2  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE (username == 'David') LIMIT 1
(0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "follows"  WHERE "follows"."followable_id" = ? AND "follows"."followable_type" = ? AND "follows"."blocked" = 'f'  [["followable_id", 3], ["followable_type", "User"]]
(0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "follows"  WHERE "follows"."blocked" = 'f' AND "follows"."follower_id" = 2 AND "follows"."follower_type" = 'User' AND "follows"."followable_id" = 3 AND "follows"."followable_type" = 'User'
Rendered users/_links.html.erb (1.2ms)
Rendered users/show.html.erb within layouts/application (7.8ms)
Rendered layouts/_app_sidebar.html.erb (0.8ms)
Mailboxer::Conversation Load (0.6ms)  SELECT DISTINCT "mailboxer_conversations".* FROM "mailboxer_conversations" INNER JOIN "mailboxer_notifications" ON "mailboxer_notifications"."conversation_id" = "mailboxer_conversations"."id" AND "mailboxer_notifications"."type" IN ('Mailboxer::Message') INNER JOIN "mailboxer_receipts" ON "mailboxer_receipts"."notification_id" = "mailboxer_notifications"."id" WHERE "mailboxer_notifications"."type" = 'Mailboxer::Message' AND "mailboxer_receipts"."receiver_id" = 2 AND "mailboxer_receipts"."receiver_type" = 'User'  ORDER BY mailboxer_conversations.updated_at DESC
Mailboxer::Message Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "mailboxer_notifications".* FROM "mailboxer_notifications"  WHERE "mailboxer_notifications"."type" IN ('Mailboxer::Message') AND "mailboxer_notifications"."conversation_id" = ?  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["conversation_id", 37]]
User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
Mailboxer::Message Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "mailboxer_notifications".* FROM "mailboxer_notifications"  WHERE "mailboxer_notifications"."type" IN ('Mailboxer::Message') AND "mailboxer_notifications"."conversation_id" = ?  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["conversation_id", 44]]
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
Mailboxer::Message Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "mailboxer_notifications".* FROM "mailboxer_notifications"  WHERE "mailboxer_notifications"."type" IN ('Mailboxer::Message') AND "mailboxer_notifications"."conversation_id" = ?  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["conversation_id", 45]]
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
Mailboxer::Message Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "mailboxer_notifications".* FROM "mailboxer_notifications"  WHERE "mailboxer_notifications"."type" IN ('Mailboxer::Message') AND "mailboxer_notifications"."conversation_id" = ?  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["conversation_id", 46]]
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
Mailboxer::Message Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "mailboxer_notifications".* FROM "mailboxer_notifications"  WHERE "mailboxer_notifications"."type" IN ('Mailboxer::Message') AND "mailboxer_notifications"."conversation_id" = ?  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["conversation_id", 43]]
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
Mailboxer::Message Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "mailboxer_notifications".* FROM "mailboxer_notifications"  WHERE "mailboxer_notifications"."type" IN ('Mailboxer::Message') AND "mailboxer_notifications"."conversation_id" = ?  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["conversation_id", 42]]
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
Mailboxer::Message Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "mailboxer_notifications".* FROM "mailboxer_notifications"  WHERE "mailboxer_notifications"."type" IN ('Mailboxer::Message') AND "mailboxer_notifications"."conversation_id" = ?  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["conversation_id", 41]]
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
Mailboxer::Message Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "mailboxer_notifications".* FROM "mailboxer_notifications"  WHERE "mailboxer_notifications"."type" IN ('Mailboxer::Message') AND "mailboxer_notifications"."conversation_id" = ?  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["conversation_id", 40]]
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
Mailboxer::Message Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "mailboxer_notifications".* FROM "mailboxer_notifications"  WHERE "mailboxer_notifications"."type" IN ('Mailboxer::Message') AND "mailboxer_notifications"."conversation_id" = ?  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["conversation_id", 39]]
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
Mailboxer::Message Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "mailboxer_notifications".* FROM "mailboxer_notifications"  WHERE "mailboxer_notifications"."type" IN ('Mailboxer::Message') AND "mailboxer_notifications"."conversation_id" = ?  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["conversation_id", 38]]
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
Mailboxer::Message Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "mailboxer_notifications".* FROM "mailboxer_notifications"  WHERE "mailboxer_notifications"."type" IN ('Mailboxer::Message') AND "mailboxer_notifications"."conversation_id" = ?  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["conversation_id", 36]]
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
Mailboxer::Message Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "mailboxer_notifications".* FROM "mailboxer_notifications"  WHERE "mailboxer_notifications"."type" IN ('Mailboxer::Message') AND "mailboxer_notifications"."conversation_id" = ?  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["conversation_id", 35]]
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
Mailboxer::Message Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "mailboxer_notifications".* FROM "mailboxer_notifications"  WHERE "mailboxer_notifications"."type" IN ('Mailboxer::Message') AND "mailboxer_notifications"."conversation_id" = ?  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["conversation_id", 34]]
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
Mailboxer::Message Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "mailboxer_notifications".* FROM "mailboxer_notifications"  WHERE "mailboxer_notifications"."type" IN ('Mailboxer::Message') AND "mailboxer_notifications"."conversation_id" = ?  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["conversation_id", 33]]
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
Mailboxer::Message Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "mailboxer_notifications".* FROM "mailboxer_notifications"  WHERE "mailboxer_notifications"."type" IN ('Mailboxer::Message') AND "mailboxer_notifications"."conversation_id" = ?  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["conversation_id", 32]]
CACHE (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
Mailboxer::Message Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "mailboxer_notifications".* FROM "mailboxer_notifications"  WHERE "mailboxer_notifications"."type" IN ('Mailboxer::Message') AND "mailboxer_notifications"."conversation_id" = ?  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["conversation_id", 31]]
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
Mailboxer::Message Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "mailboxer_notifications".* FROM "mailboxer_notifications"  WHERE "mailboxer_notifications"."type" IN ('Mailboxer::Message') AND "mailboxer_notifications"."conversation_id" = ?  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["conversation_id", 30]]
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
Mailboxer::Message Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "mailboxer_notifications".* FROM "mailboxer_notifications"  WHERE "mailboxer_notifications"."type" IN ('Mailboxer::Message') AND "mailboxer_notifications"."conversation_id" = ?  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["conversation_id", 29]]
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
Mailboxer::Message Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "mailboxer_notifications".* FROM "mailboxer_notifications"  WHERE "mailboxer_notifications"."type" IN ('Mailboxer::Message') AND "mailboxer_notifications"."conversation_id" = ?  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["conversation_id", 28]]
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
Mailboxer::Message Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "mailboxer_notifications".* FROM "mailboxer_notifications"  WHERE "mailboxer_notifications"."type" IN ('Mailboxer::Message') AND "mailboxer_notifications"."conversation_id" = ?  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["conversation_id", 27]]
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
Mailboxer::Message Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "mailboxer_notifications".* FROM "mailboxer_notifications"  WHERE "mailboxer_notifications"."type" IN ('Mailboxer::Message') AND "mailboxer_notifications"."conversation_id" = ?  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["conversation_id", 26]]
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
Mailboxer::Message Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "mailboxer_notifications".* FROM "mailboxer_notifications"  WHERE "mailboxer_notifications"."type" IN ('Mailboxer::Message') AND "mailboxer_notifications"."conversation_id" = ?  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["conversation_id", 25]]
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
Mailboxer::Message Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "mailboxer_notifications".* FROM "mailboxer_notifications"  WHERE "mailboxer_notifications"."type" IN ('Mailboxer::Message') AND "mailboxer_notifications"."conversation_id" = ?  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["conversation_id", 24]]
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
Mailboxer::Message Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "mailboxer_notifications".* FROM "mailboxer_notifications"  WHERE "mailboxer_notifications"."type" IN ('Mailboxer::Message') AND "mailboxer_notifications"."conversation_id" = ?  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["conversation_id", 23]]
CACHE (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
Mailboxer::Message Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "mailboxer_notifications".* FROM "mailboxer_notifications"  WHERE "mailboxer_notifications"."type" IN ('Mailboxer::Message') AND "mailboxer_notifications"."conversation_id" = ?  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["conversation_id", 22]]
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
Mailboxer::Message Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "mailboxer_notifications".* FROM "mailboxer_notifications"  WHERE "mailboxer_notifications"."type" IN ('Mailboxer::Message') AND "mailboxer_notifications"."conversation_id" = ?  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["conversation_id", 21]]
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
Mailboxer::Message Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "mailboxer_notifications".* FROM "mailboxer_notifications"  WHERE "mailboxer_notifications"."type" IN ('Mailboxer::Message') AND "mailboxer_notifications"."conversation_id" = ?  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["conversation_id", 20]]
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
Mailboxer::Message Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "mailboxer_notifications".* FROM "mailboxer_notifications"  WHERE "mailboxer_notifications"."type" IN ('Mailboxer::Message') AND "mailboxer_notifications"."conversation_id" = ?  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["conversation_id", 19]]
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
Mailboxer::Message Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "mailboxer_notifications".* FROM "mailboxer_notifications"  WHERE "mailboxer_notifications"."type" IN ('Mailboxer::Message') AND "mailboxer_notifications"."conversation_id" = ?  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["conversation_id", 18]]
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
Mailboxer::Message Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "mailboxer_notifications".* FROM "mailboxer_notifications"  WHERE "mailboxer_notifications"."type" IN ('Mailboxer::Message') AND "mailboxer_notifications"."conversation_id" = ?  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["conversation_id", 17]]
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
Mailboxer::Message Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "mailboxer_notifications".* FROM "mailboxer_notifications"  WHERE "mailboxer_notifications"."type" IN ('Mailboxer::Message') AND "mailboxer_notifications"."conversation_id" = ?  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["conversation_id", 16]]
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
Mailboxer::Message Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "mailboxer_notifications".* FROM "mailboxer_notifications"  WHERE "mailboxer_notifications"."type" IN ('Mailboxer::Message') AND "mailboxer_notifications"."conversation_id" = ?  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["conversation_id", 15]]
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
Mailboxer::Message Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "mailboxer_notifications".* FROM "mailboxer_notifications"  WHERE "mailboxer_notifications"."type" IN ('Mailboxer::Message') AND "mailboxer_notifications"."conversation_id" = ?  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["conversation_id", 14]]
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
Mailboxer::Message Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "mailboxer_notifications".* FROM "mailboxer_notifications"  WHERE "mailboxer_notifications"."type" IN ('Mailboxer::Message') AND "mailboxer_notifications"."conversation_id" = ?  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["conversation_id", 13]]
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
Mailboxer::Message Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "mailboxer_notifications".* FROM "mailboxer_notifications"  WHERE "mailboxer_notifications"."type" IN ('Mailboxer::Message') AND "mailboxer_notifications"."conversation_id" = ?  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["conversation_id", 12]]
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
Mailboxer::Message Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "mailboxer_notifications".* FROM "mailboxer_notifications"  WHERE "mailboxer_notifications"."type" IN ('Mailboxer::Message') AND "mailboxer_notifications"."conversation_id" = ?  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["conversation_id", 11]]
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
Mailboxer::Message Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "mailboxer_notifications".* FROM "mailboxer_notifications"  WHERE "mailboxer_notifications"."type" IN ('Mailboxer::Message') AND "mailboxer_notifications"."conversation_id" = ?  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["conversation_id", 10]]
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
Mailboxer::Message Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "mailboxer_notifications".* FROM "mailboxer_notifications"  WHERE "mailboxer_notifications"."type" IN ('Mailboxer::Message') AND "mailboxer_notifications"."conversation_id" = ?  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["conversation_id", 9]]
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
Mailboxer::Message Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "mailboxer_notifications".* FROM "mailboxer_notifications"  WHERE "mailboxer_notifications"."type" IN ('Mailboxer::Message') AND "mailboxer_notifications"."conversation_id" = ?  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["conversation_id", 8]]
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
Mailboxer::Message Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "mailboxer_notifications".* FROM "mailboxer_notifications"  WHERE "mailboxer_notifications"."type" IN ('Mailboxer::Message') AND "mailboxer_notifications"."conversation_id" = ?  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["conversation_id", 7]]
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
Mailboxer::Message Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "mailboxer_notifications".* FROM "mailboxer_notifications"  WHERE "mailboxer_notifications"."type" IN ('Mailboxer::Message') AND "mailboxer_notifications"."conversation_id" = ?  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["conversation_id", 6]]
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
Mailboxer::Message Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "mailboxer_notifications".* FROM "mailboxer_notifications"  WHERE "mailboxer_notifications"."type" IN ('Mailboxer::Message') AND "mailboxer_notifications"."conversation_id" = ?  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["conversation_id", 5]]
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
Mailboxer::Message Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "mailboxer_notifications".* FROM "mailboxer_notifications"  WHERE "mailboxer_notifications"."type" IN ('Mailboxer::Message') AND "mailboxer_notifications"."conversation_id" = ?  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["conversation_id", 4]]
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
Mailboxer::Message Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "mailboxer_notifications".* FROM "mailboxer_notifications"  WHERE "mailboxer_notifications"."type" IN ('Mailboxer::Message') AND "mailboxer_notifications"."conversation_id" = ?  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["conversation_id", 3]]
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
Mailboxer::Message Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "mailboxer_notifications".* FROM "mailboxer_notifications"  WHERE "mailboxer_notifications"."type" IN ('Mailboxer::Message') AND "mailboxer_notifications"."conversation_id" = ?  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["conversation_id", 2]]
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
Mailboxer::Message Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "mailboxer_notifications".* FROM "mailboxer_notifications"  WHERE "mailboxer_notifications"."type" IN ('Mailboxer::Message') AND "mailboxer_notifications"."conversation_id" = ?  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1  [["conversation_id", 1]]
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
Rendered mailboxer/conversations/_conversation.html.erb (155.4ms)
Rendered layouts/_app_header.html.erb (159.5ms)
Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 223ms (Views: 206.2ms | ActiveRecord: 13.5ms)
```

Comment: This arrangement should work. Are you sure you have the relevant data in db?

Comment: Yes, I used the rails console to confirm.

Comment: And there's no mention of the posts table at all in the logs.. so basically, it's not even being requested.

Comment: Can you post your `server log`?

Comment: Try: `<% @user.posted_posts.each do |post| %>` instead?

Comment: @Surya - I'm ashamed that I didn't try that earlier. Thank you! post it as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out that you missed `.each`:

```
<% @user.posted_posts.each do |post| %>
```